# I'm having trouble doing basic transforms in 2.82

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, transforms, error

Transforming objects in Blender causes the origin to move and an "outline" but that's the only thing it seems to move until I switch to edit mode and everything is together.

Not entirely sure what happened, but I just cleared all preferences and uninstalled and reinstalled blender and it still does it.

[image]

[Video Here](https://youtu.be/5YvfaVzpSkk)

This issue does not persist in blender 2.79 only in 2.80, 2.82, 2.83b

EDIT: As it turns out my graphics driver needed to be fudges as the one that is for the card has this issue. The driver for a card 2-3 models newer works just fine AFAICT.

Comment: HI, welcome. It should not, for sure. It could be a glitch with your pc video card drivers, try to update them to the latest stable versions. Also you could try to download a blender .zip version, extract it in a folder and run blender directly from that folder. Sometimes it is different, since this zip version is not "installed", and sometimes the "installer" may introduce issues of its own due to several reasons. It could work better.

Comment: I just tried that and also reinstalling my graphics drivers and neither of those things changed anything for the portable version or the install. It doesn't glitch or anything, it almost seems like something's just set wrong or selection is just set wrong but I'm too new to the new interface to tell.