# Moving Cube in Object Mode leaves Outline of the Cube on Screen

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode, object-mode

When I want to move my cube in object mode, I see another cube. This seems to be the same cube but in edit mode.

Here are two screenshots, when I tried to move the first cube in object mode.

NOTE: the 3D view (N) are all unlocked so the problem comes from something else.

[image: cube]

[image: ghost cube]

Comment: Hi. Please use [StackExchange's built-in tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83096/how-to-place-an-image-in-a-stack-overflow-question) to post images.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173982/selected-mesh-will-not-move-in-object-mode?r=SearchResults https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177854/blender-2-82-issue-moving-objects#comment298054_177854 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176595/im-having-trouble-doing-basic-transforms-in-2-82?r=SearchResults https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176715/only-the-objects-outline-is-moving-instead-of-object?r=SearchResults

Comment: Is this a default or a custom render engine? Looks like movement did not trigger a Depsgraph update which did not trigger redraw. I used to have this issue when developing a custom render engine.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Blender then reinstall.

Comment: Blende does have a full-fledged installer, although it is optional.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a temporary fix to this, that works for me at least. With your cube selected, first enter Edit Mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), then deselect everything (double-tap <kbd>A</kbd>), then go back to Object Mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), and then deselect everything again (double-tap <kbd>A</kbd>). Then when you select the cube again and try to move it, it should be fine. I have absolutely no idea why this works though.